# Saving Attachment from Email Part using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, imap

I've come across a bit of a problem and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'm writing a email parser that parses emails and extracts particular info.

1. It parses plain text emails(the emails are in a set format) using regex, this works fine.
2. If an email has an attachment which is of type 3 && encoding = 3 && disposition = attachment then save the attachment to local disk.

My problem is step 2:

I foreach through each email structure if it has more than 2 parts I attempt to decode the attachment and save it to disk, but this is failing.

If I try to simply use file_put_contents I get a **0 KB File**, I have given full permissions to the wamp server user, So I do not *think* it's file permissions and I have verified I can write by using mkdir.

```
file_put_contents(APPPATH . "attachments/". $partofpart->dparameters[0]->value, $partofpart); //$partofpart is part[2] of the full email structure
```

So I attempted to decode the part and save the decoded part instead using file_put_contents

```
$attachment = base64_decode($partofpart);
var_dump($attachment);
//then save the attachment with attachment name 
file_put_contents(APPPATH . "attachments/". $partofpart->dparameters[0]->value, $attachment);
```

but this returns an error saying base64_decode requires an string not an object, how do I then convert my email-part-attachment to a string for use by base64_decode?

Even just writing that out I feel I'm missing something obvious and shouldn't require the extra steps.

Am I right in thinking the part **IS** the attachment? All the parameters lead me to believe so, Type, Subtype, size etc are all correct for the attachment.

Link to the entire [scraper model](http://pastebin.com/Q0FXuy54)

Thanks for reading and any help.

Below is a vardump of parts that meet the type/encoding/disposition checks

[image: Var dump of emails that pass checks]

**I have worked out the problem, I was not fetching the actual pdf back just its structure**

So I wrote a function to retrieve the body of the particular email then used imap_base64 to encode then finally file_put_contents.

```
function getAttachment($msg_index, $part)
        {
        $mailbody = imap_fetchbody($this->conn,$msg_index,$part);

        return $mailbody;

    }

$attachment = imap_base64($this->email_model->getAttachment($email['index'], "2"));

    //mkdir(APPPATH . "attachmentzs/");

    //then save the attachment with attachment name 
    file_put_contents(APPPATH . "attachments/".       $partofpart->dparameters[0]->value, $attachment);
```

Comment: so do a `var_dump($partofpart)` to see what it's in there. obviously it's an object, so maybe you need to do `base64_decode($partofpart->something->deeper->down)`

Comment: I have done a var_dump of partofpart thats how I know it has the right file type and sub type and file size, I was under the impression the entire $partofpart IS the attachment there is nothing deeper down than the type/disposition/size/filename/, nothing that points to any of them being the attachment(in this case a pdf).

Comment: yeah, but base64_decode knows nothing about "attachments" and couldn't care less. it expects a STRING. b64_dec won't know what part of the object you're trying to stuff in there is the actual b64 data

Comment: I've updated the question with a var_dump of both particular attachmentparts, I cannot see any of them that would match what base64_decode requires, this is my problem, I could be going about it completely the wrong way, I am unsure this is why I asked and listed my reasoning.